# Getting battery stats of all apps in android

Tags: android, batterylevel, batterymanager

I am working on a battery monitoring app in which I have to show battery usage for all apps. After a lot of googling I found there a only way to do so is using command line

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterystats --charged --checkin
```

The above command will provide all battery stats but I don't know how can I get this data in my code?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Following code to show Summary of all apps battery usage, So you can try this.

`Intent sample = new Intent("android.intent.action.POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY");
startActivity(sample);`

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want to use this data to make my custom list.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab dumpsys information on the device, but it does require permissions which are not granted to regular applications.

The *shell-user* has permission to run the command however - if you're running an on-device test using [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation) you can use [Instrumentation.getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)) to execute the command as the shell user.